# Vue3 Add html to existing project

Tags: vuejs3

I’ve built my first project and have run the build process. I have my index.html file and it works if opened directly.

I’ve copied the code into an existing html page and the initial page load is fine. However, when props get updated, binding (v-if statements) no longer works.

Any help would be great

Edit with code example

```
<script>

    import { ref } from "vue";
    import Determining from './Determining.vue'
    import Ready from './Ready.vue'

    export default {

        components: {
            'Determining': Determining,
            'Ready': Ready,
        },

        setup() {

            let checkout = ref({
                state: 'determining',
            });

            return {
                checkout,
            };

        },

        created() {
            this.checkout.state = 'ready';
            console.log("I am getting here");
        }
   }
</script>

<template>
    <Determining v-if="checkout.state == 'determining'" />
    <Ready v-if="checkout.state == 'ready'" />
</template>
```

The determining state is shown when the page first loads. The console log is firing in setup, but Ready component is not showing

---

**Progress**

I've narrowed it down to other javascript running on the page.
Any javascript, even just

`<script>console.log("hello");</script>`

Is enough to break it.
Other than adding additional javascript to Vue, is there anyway around it?

Comment: You shouldn't use `created()` in combination with `setup()`: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-lifecycle-hooks.html
It is surprising that the log statement is fired though. You could use the `onBeforeMount` hook instead. But anyway, if it would work, you would never see the determining state as it would change the ref before the actual rendering which is done when it mounts.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm not wrong, you can't access composition api or `setup()` variables in options api (such as `created`, `mounted`, `data`, `methods` etc). You can use `beforeMount` as @Thomas commented or `onMounted` by importing it from `vue`, for the example:

```
<script>

    import { ref, beforeCreate } from "vue";
    import Determining from './Determining.vue'
    import Ready from './Ready.vue'

    export default {

        components: {
            'Determining': Determining,
            'Ready': Ready,
        },

        setup() {
            beforeCreate(()=> {
              checkout.state.value = 'ready';
              console.log("I am getting here");
            })

            let checkout = ref({
                state: 'determining',
            });

            return {
                checkout,
            };

        }
   }
</script>

<template>
    <Determining v-if="checkout.state == 'determining'" />
    <Ready v-if="checkout.state == 'ready'" />
</template>
```

if you want it more simple, you can use script sugar setup, this way you don't need to return in `stup()`. It can make your code simpler but if you want to define props, the approach is different

```
<script setup>

    import { ref, beforeCreate } from "vue";
    import Determining from './Determining.vue'
    import Ready from './Ready.vue'

    beforeCreate(()=> {
      checkout.state.value = 'ready';
      console.log("I am getting here");
    })

    let checkout = ref({
        state: 'determining',
    });
</script>

<template>
    <Determining v-if="checkout.state == 'determining'" />
    <Ready v-if="checkout.state == 'ready'" />
</template>
```